# Android Looper.prepare() and AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler

Hi I have some questions regarding Looper.prepare() and AsyncTasks.

In my app I have an AsyncTask that's starting other AsyncTasks. I had 2 AsyncTasks Search and GetImage. The GetImage task is executed several times within the Search task. It works fine.

However recently I implemented image caching as described here: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

After I implemented this I started getting intermittent crashes

02-09 17:40:43.334: W/System.err(25652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I'm not sure where I should call prepare(). Here's a rough outline of the code

```
Search extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(){
        ArrayList<Object> objs = getDataFromServer();
        ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
        for(Object o: objs){
            //multiple AsyncTasks may be started while creating views
            views.add(createView(o));
        }
        for(View v: views){
            publishProgess(v);
        }
   }
}

public View createView(Object o){

    //create a view
    ImageView iv = .....;
    ImageDownloader.getInstance().download(url,iv);
}
```

The ImageDownloader can be seen in the link above, in it is another AsyncTask to download the image aswell. It also contains a Handler and Runnable for purging the cache which is reset every time a download occurs. I did make one change to the ImageDownloader, I made it a singleton.

```
 public static ImageDownloader getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        //tried adding it here but it results in occasional
        //cannot create more than one looper per thread error
        Looper.prepare();
        instance= new ImageDownloader();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

The ImageDownloader download method may be called 10's of times, which is creating an AysncTask for each of the downloads. So I've been scratching my head for the last few days, Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is really going on is you are attempting to perform something on a background thread that requires the UI thread to run.

The Looper is a part of the system that ensures that transactions are done in order, and the device is responding as it should.

95% of the time when you get the Looper error, what it really means is you need to move part of your code to the UI thread, in Asynctask this means moving it to either `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate`.

In your case it appears as if you are adding views, which is part of the UI and therefor would cause a problem. If that is not in fact what is causing the problem, an examination of the stacktrace should give you some clues.

As a side note, if you MUST call `Looper.prepare()` I would call it at the beginning of your thread. However, this is generally recommended to avoid the need to call it.

Comment: Do you mean I shouldn't spawn an AsyncTask from within an AysncTask without calling Looper.prepare() or better yet don't do it at all? Also if I call Looper.prepare() at the start of doInBackground() in the Search task will that handle spawning multiple AsyncTasks from doInBackGround() ?

Comment: My only comment to that is I have heard android development staff mention that they would like to restrict Async Task to only allowing one at a time to prevent "abuse". I would recommend devising a more streamlined method to perform your results.

Comment: while @Pyrodante is totally right, unless u r using AsyncTask#executeOnExecutor(), you don't need Looper.prepare(). Your problem is updating UI from background process as already pryodante explained. AsyncTask#executeOnExecutor() is good for putting thread in a new thread pool to avoid long waiting of busy queues. Any how for using that, precautions are advised. you would better read the doc first.